# How to find element if XCUIElementTypeCell is there iOS Appium Mobile automation

Tags: java, ios, appium, appium-ios

I am writing automation for ios mobile app, using appium and java in IntelliJ
While inspecting the elements accessibility id is not there, and the app structure contains class names like this XCUIElementTypeCell, which I am not able to click
Below is the XPath which I am getting while inspection on appium
But unable to click on this XPath, please help

```
//XCUIElementTypeApplication[@name="sample"]/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeTable/XCUIElementTypeCell[1]
```

Comment: please let me know if you need any other details

Comment: 1). Post a screenshot of the storyboard where you have set the accessibility ID, or paste the code where you set it, in here. 2). Post a screenshot of the app so we can see what it is you are trying to tap and where it is. 3). Have you tried checking if each piece of the xpath to see where the problem is? 4). personal opinion, I hate appium and find it very flaky. I use the native XCUITest in xcode instead. The combination of Swift + the click to record button, is thousands of times better than appium

Comment: Ok, I understand your points. Actually, I am new to ios mobile automation so not sure if which one is better to use. The thing I am trying to do - writing functional test scripts(in java, appium) for ios application. Do you think XCUITest work better in writing functional test scenarios. Also, I want to know - do I need to learn swift for that?

Comment: The only advantage to appium is the fact of being able to share some tests across iOS and Android. This can often not work due to differences in how the apps are built, making it less of a bonus. I've had more issues than success with it. XCUITest is much more stable, and has more features. If you are only doing iOS automation, theres next to no advantage to using appium. Yes to use a native Swift test framework you need to learn swift and xcode